# How can I call an object-specific function from a mouseclick event?

Tags: javascript, object, event-handling

I'm new to javascript objects, and I can't figure out a way to "simply" create HTML elements from an object's method and assign click listener to it.
even worst, I've dramaticly reduced my issue to : I can't add a listener to an existing HTML element and ask it to trigger this specific Object to call a method.
I've tryed many things, playing around with "this", adding the object itself as parameter...

Here I expect my console.log to return +1 each time I click the "+" button :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

      <div id="Score2" class="Resultat"> 0 </div>

      <button id="addbtn">+</button>

      <script>
            item_manager = {

                  test_value : 0,
                  add_btn : null,

                  set_add_btn : function(elt, id)
                  {
                        this.add_btn=document.getElementById(id);
                        this.add_btn.addEventListener("click", elt.add_one, false);
                  },
                  add_one: function ()
                  {
                        this.test_value += 1;
                        console.log(this.test_value);
                        console.log(this);
                  }
            };
            item_for_tests = Object.create(item_manager)
            item_for_tests.set_add_btn(item_for_tests,"addbtn");
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add event handler, `this` becomes the element on which the event is called. So in your case `this` inside `add_one` becomes `addbtn`

You need to `bind` the object to the function so that this will correctly point to the object that you wish to operate.

You need to change this line

```
this.add_btn.addEventListener("click", elt.add_one, false);
```

to

```
this.add_btn.addEventListener("click", elt.add_one.bind(elt), false);
```

Comment: thx a lot, this post might be a duplicate, I've found the answers on an another situation :)